# Not getting value in form variable in td where user input?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table inside a form in jsp in want the value for etc_labour:

```
<form>
<table border="1" width="1080px" id="someTableID">
//Dynamic Row
<tr>
<td bgcolor="white" width="110px" align="right"> <input type="text" name="etc_labour" size="13"  value="Test" id="fname"/> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<form>
```

Javascript:
The innerHTML is not bring value etc_labour which we give as input,

```
  var table = document.getElementById('someTableID');
    for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
            alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
        }
    }
```

Can you help me to get the value in the input etc_labour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

table.rows[x].cells[y].querySelector('input').value;

Answer (score 1):

Using innerHTML you get all the content inside an element. If you just want to get the value you should use something like this:

```
table.rows[r].cells[c].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting the form and then accessing the value of the input element through it? Like below

```
const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
const etcLabourValue = form.elements['etc_labour'].value;
```

No looping and thus no performance drawback